# Fill N/A with previous day data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and it just has data for weekday. Below is sample dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'BAS_DT': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07'], 
                   'CUS_NO': [np.nan, np.nan, '900816636', '900816636', '900816946', '900816931', np.nan, np.nan],
                   'VALUE': [np.nan, np.nan, 10, 10, 7, 8, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'BR': [np.nan, np.nan, 100, 100, 200, 300, np.nan, np.nan]})
df

    BAS_DT      CUS_NO      VALUE   BR
0   2023-01-02  NaN         NaN     NaN
1   2023-01-03  NaN         NaN     NaN
2   2023-01-04  900816636   10.0    100.0
3   2023-01-05  900816636   10.0    100.0
4   2023-01-05  900816946   7.0     200.0
5   2023-01-05  900816931   8.0     300.0
6   2023-01-06  NaN         NaN     NaN
7   2023-01-07  NaN         NaN     NaN
```

I want to fill `2023-01-06` and `2023-01-07` same with `2023-01-05`. I tried `ffill` but it just fill with the first row that closest to NaN row. Below is my desired Output:

```
    BAS_DT      CUS_NO      VALUE   BR
0   2023-01-02  NaN         NaN     NaN
1   2023-01-03  NaN         NaN     NaN
2   2023-01-04  900816636   10.0    100.0
3   2023-01-05  900816636   10.0    100.0
4   2023-01-05  900816946   7.0     200.0
5   2023-01-05  900816931   8.0     300.0
7   2023-01-06  900816636   10.0    100.0
8   2023-01-06  900816946   7.0     200.0
9   2023-01-06  900816931   8.0     300.0
10  2023-01-07  900816636   10.0    100.0
11  2023-01-07  900816946   7.0     200.0
12  2023-01-07  900816931   8.0     300.0
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain why you have data for 2023-01-07 in the output? I thought you wanted to ffill grill the **previous** day?

Comment: HI @mozway, 2023-01-07 is Sunday, and my goal is fill Saturday and Sunday (now NA) with Friday data.

Comment: Will there ever be values after the second group of `NaN` values?

Comment: @Nick: Yep, it will. From next Monday to Friday, it will have new data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could group by the `BAS_DT`, aggregating `CUS_NO` into a list where there is more than one value in the group, then `ffill` and `explode`:

```
out = (df
    .groupby('BAS_DT')
    .agg(lambda g:list(g) if len(g) > 1 else g)
    .ffill()
    .explode('CUS_NO')
    .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
        BAS_DT     CUS_NO
0   2023-01-02        NaN
1   2023-01-03        NaN
2   2023-01-04  900816636
3   2023-01-05  900816636
4   2023-01-05  900816946
5   2023-01-05  900816931
6   2023-01-06  900816636
7   2023-01-06  900816946
8   2023-01-06  900816931
9   2023-01-07  900816636
10  2023-01-07  900816946
11  2023-01-07  900816931
```

Note that for the update to the question, you will need to use

```
    .explode(['CUS_NO', 'VALUE', 'BR'])
```

but otherwise the code will work unchanged as long as you are using pandas 2.0 or later.

Comment: Hi Nick, I edited my question with more columns. Your code worked with my sample here in the question but with real data it raised column must be a scalar. I used `.explode(['CUS_NO', 'VALUE', 'BR']`

Comment: Ok I got it, I will post a new one.

Comment: @hoatran what version of pandas are you using? it works fine in 2.1.4

Comment: Yep maybe it's problem of pandas old version. I'm using 1.2.4 in my company PC but my PC is 2.0.1 and it worked. I will update my pandas.

Comment: Yeah, 1.2.4 is very old now. It should work in 2.x

Answer (score 2):

You could [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), and reshape back to long format:

```
out = (df.assign(n=df.groupby('BAS_DT').cumcount())
       .replace('', float('nan'))
       .pivot(index='BAS_DT', columns='n')
       .ffill()
       .stack(dropna=False)
       .reset_index('BAS_DT')
       .sort_values(by=['BAS_DT', 'CUS_NO'], na_position='first')
       .loc[lambda d: d['CUS_NO'].notna() | ~d[['BAS_DT', 'CUS_NO']].duplicated()]
      )

out
```

Output:

```
       BAS_DT     CUS_NO  VALUE     BR
n                                     
0  2023-01-02        NaN    NaN    NaN
0  2023-01-03        NaN    NaN    NaN
1  2023-01-04        NaN    NaN    NaN
0  2023-01-04  900816636   10.0  100.0
0  2023-01-05  900816636   10.0  100.0
2  2023-01-05  900816931    8.0  300.0
1  2023-01-05  900816946    7.0  200.0
0  2023-01-06  900816636   10.0  100.0
2  2023-01-06  900816931    8.0  300.0
1  2023-01-06  900816946    7.0  200.0
0  2023-01-07  900816636   10.0  100.0
2  2023-01-07  900816931    8.0  300.0
1  2023-01-07  900816946    7.0  200.0
```

Intermediate before the `stack` step:

```
               CUS_NO                      
n                   0          1          2
BAS_DT                                     
2023-01-02        NaN        NaN        NaN
2023-01-03        NaN        NaN        NaN
2023-01-04  900816636        NaN        NaN
2023-01-05  900816636  900816946  900816931
2023-01-06  900816636  900816946  900816931
2023-01-07  900816636  900816946  900816931
```

Comment: Thank you, but with this code, it will contain `2023-01-04` with na value. How can I fix it?

Comment: @hoatran Oops I missed that. Let me update it

Comment: @hoatran here it is

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked, but I don't know which one should I choose as accepted answer between you and Nick.

Comment: @hoatran take your time, test it with your data and make your decision. Both answers have a different logic and potentially different strengths and weaknesses ;)

Comment: Couldn't have put it better myself :)

Comment: @mozway: I'm sorry but I think I have to edit my question. With more columns I don't know how to do.

Comment: @hoatran it works fine for me with the latest pandas version (see updated output)

Comment: You do have an extra row for `2023-01-04` with `NaN` in it...

Comment: @Nick minor detail (I was on my phone), you need to select the correct column for de-duplication ;)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use:

```
cols = ['BAS_DT', 'CUS_NO']
split = df['CUS_NO'].isna().idxmin()

# Create dense matrix
df1 = (pd.crosstab(df.loc[split:, 'BAS_DT'], df.loc[split:, 'CUS_NO'].ffill())
         .cumsum().astype(bool))

# Restore shape
df1 = (df1.mul(df1.columns).unstack()
          .loc[lambda x: x != '']
          .index.to_frame(index=False))

# Build a new dataframe
out = (pd.concat([df.loc[:split], df1])
         .drop_duplicates(['CUS_NO', 'BAS_DT'], ignore_index=True))
```

Output:

```
>>> out
        BAS_DT     CUS_NO
0   2023-01-02        NaN
1   2023-01-03        NaN
2   2023-01-04  900816636
3   2023-01-05  900816636
4   2023-01-06  900816636
5   2023-01-07  900816636
6   2023-01-05  900816931
7   2023-01-06  900816931
8   2023-01-07  900816931
9   2023-01-05  900816946
10  2023-01-06  900816946
11  2023-01-07  900816946
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the desired output by first forward filling the missing values in the 'CUS_NO' column and then duplicating the rows for each unique value in 'CUS_NO'.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your original DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'BAS_DT': ['2023-01-02', '2023-01-03', '2023-01-04', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-05', '2023-01-06', '2023-01-07'], 
   'CUS_NO': [np.nan, np.nan, '900816636', '900816636', '900816946', '900816931', np.nan, np.nan]})


# Convert 'BAS_DT' to datetime
df['BAS_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(df['BAS_DT'])

# Forward fill missing values in 'CUS_NO'
df['CUS_NO'] = df['CUS_NO'].fillna(method='ffill')

# Duplicate rows for each unique value in 'CUS_NO'
result_df = df[df['CUS_NO'] != ''].explode('CUS_NO').reset_index(drop=True)

print(result_df)
```

[Click on this to execute the code](https://replit.com/@bhanu_tejtej/pandastest)

Comment: Seems you made changes to question. Check now I have updated the code.

Comment: Hi, tried but it looks same with just use `ffill`